# how to arrange the input text/file in a line

Tags: html, css

I am designing a web page with multi line `Label name & input type file`. i tried very hard to arrange in same line sequence but failed to do. Is there any idea about it?

please take a look [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/LRTXG/12/) , it looks very ugly and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are looking for, but check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRTXG/17/) changes I had made.  I modified both CSS classes a little bit.

Comment: great ! this is what i was looking for. but someone told that `not to use float` as it is depricated now. BTW thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know where you heard that float is deprecated?  It is perfectly fine to use float, but you need to make sure how you use it, for inline content like this there are no problems.

Comment: floats aren't deprecated. There is now other solutions for positioning (display: inline-block, display: table-cell and so on, depending on your support of old browsers and the graceful degradation your client will accept) but you can still use floats. Still the better (and only) way to wrap text around an image in your content. That's what it was designed for. But for positioning blocks, use floats only if you don't know of any better solution.

Comment: thanks Andrew & Felipe ! one of my collegue instructed me once and he is quite senior to me :(

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/forms/

Answer (score 1):

now it looks good :)

**html**

```
<div id="divid1" align="center" style="padding:50px;">
  <div class="formrow">
    <label class="labelname" for="hide-file">Select Image* :</label>     
    <input type="file" name="file1" class="hide-file" />
  </div>
  <div class="formrow">
    <label class="labelname" for="hide-file">XML File* :</label>
    <input type="file" name="file2" class="hide-file" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.labelname {
  background: green;
  font: bold 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left
}

.hide-file {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0.5;
 float: right
}

.formrow {
 width: 400px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRTXG/24/) with the following modifications:

- removing deprecated attributes align from div and moving inlined CSS style (style attribute) to the CSS file
- same for b element used for the text of the label: span is better, and it's already bold as its parent. Or font-weight: bold; would be added in CSS
- display: inline-block; is used instead of floats. No need to clear them afterward. IE7 and 6 need a fix (in comment) if you support them. This allow you to give the element a width (like you could do with any block element) and still get them on the same horizontal line (like you could do with any inline element). You'll have 4px due to whitespace in your HTML code, because whitespace shows up in inline element like two `span` separated by a space but there's a fix.

HTML code

```
<div id="divid1">
    <p>
        <label class="labelname"> <span> select Image* :</span>      
            <input type="file" name="file1" class="hide-file" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="labelname"> <span>XML File* :</span>
            <input type="file" name="file2" class="hide-file" />  
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divid1 {
    padding: 50px;
}

.labelname {
    width: 100%; /* or at least approx. 380px */
    min-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    background: lightgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

/* Only for IE7 */
/*.labelname span,
.hide-file {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
*/

.labelname span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.hide-file {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: I forgot id and for attributes on input and label, doh!